# Issue in connecting bluetooth headphones

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 22.04

I recently updated ubuntu to the latest version 22.04 and facing issue in connecting my bluetooth headphones(Sony wf c-500). The device is getting displayed twice in the blutooth manager like 1. WF-C500 2. LE_WF-C500. I tried updating repositories, reinstalling bluez and blueman and still could not find the solution. At times the device gets connected and i receive the notification but it will not play any sound and wont get it displayed on output devices in sound setting.
Reading above (without any codes) you would have realized i am completely newbie to ubuntu ;) . So step by step solutions will be more welcomed.

Answer (score -1):

This is very much a recurring problem with Linux.
You need to find out the type of your hardware bluetooth controller and then install the driver (if there is any).

You can find the type by typing in a terminal `sudo dmesg | grep -i Blue`. Look for a line that looks kind of like this:

```
[  655.928270] Bluetooth: hci1: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[  655.930889] Bluetooth: hci1: BCM20702A1 'brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd' Patch
[  657.155223] Bluetooth: hci1: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 1764
```

Or anything that looks like it might contain the type of the hardware controller. Try typing the type into Google if the output of dmesg does not tell you the company.

Best case would be if there are any more packages you can install from Ubuntu repositories. If you know the company, like Realtek or Broadcom, you might be able to locate a repository through searching aptitude (if you don't have aptitude, install it by typing `sudo apt-get install aptitude`). Assuming the company is Broadcom, you would type:

```
sudo aptitude search broadcom
```

Your output might be something like

```
i   broadcom-sta-common - Common files for the Broadcom STA Wireless driver                                       
p   broadcom-sta-dkms - dkms source for the Broadcom STA Wireless driver                                        
p   broadcom-sta-modules                                                                                                                                                
p   broadcom-sta-source - Source for the Broadcom STA Wireless driver
```

`p` means the package is not installed but available. So, if any of those say Wireless driver, install them typing `sudo aptitude install broadcom-sta-dkms` just for example.

If this solves your issues that's great, otherwise: Best of luck.

You would need to type the type into Google adding "driver installation Linux" or similar. The installation process can look many ways so I can't tell you.

The reason for this is probably that Ubuntu developers decided to discontinue some drivers, but I'm not that well informed on the packages Ubuntu ships and how they decide, so I can't tell you why the problem suddenly occurred with upgrading. It is not a first anyway.

Comment: This is all wrong. `broadcom-sta-dkms` has nothing to do with Bluetooth. And there is no evidence that OP has a Broadcom device.

Comment: please read correctly, I never said OP has a Broadcom device. These are examples from my system. made some edits to make that clearer though.
As for broadcom-sta-dkms, you're probably right. it would not hurt to install it though